# I cleaned the solution in Visual Studio 2015, and now cant open the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I cleaned the solution in Visual Studio and now, every time I try to do anything, an error pops up saying, "Could not load file or assembly, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nul or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

It wont let me save the project or anything

Comment: Close visual studio ,press (window +R) to open run command,type %temp% ,press ok and delete all temporary files, reopen visual studio and build solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the temporary files from the bin folder of main project and once again clean the solution and rebuild it so that all the packages will load again...

You can even try to restore nuget packages that are missing..

This when any package doesn't load properly during the build..